# How to supply generic type for the state-monad's method

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I am trying to create a `function` for the state monad that can receive a generic type in the `a` : 
 `newtype State s a=State { runstate::s->(s,a) }`

I want to bind only the first type of the `runstate::s->(s,a)` , and later decide what `a` should be :

So instead of something like :

```
f::Int->(Int,String)
f x | x>3 = (x, "bigger then 3")
    |otherwise =(x,"smaller then 3")

make::State Int String
make =State f
```

How can I accomplish :

```
makeFree::State Int a
makeFree=State ....
```

You might be wondering why would I need that. While I know the type of the `state` i want the result of the computation to vary.

Comment: But here the rsult of your comutation is a `String`: it is either `"bigger than 3"`, or `"smaller than 3"`. That result is already "free" in the sense that the bind function can change the result of each computation. So if you first "return" a string, then the second expression in the bind does not per se needs to be `String`.

Comment: Well i placed that as an example where i supplied a function with both variables fixed.Can i somehow let the result variable free? And define functions afterwards ? `Int->(Int, Bool)`, `Int->(Int,Char)` etc ? By free i mean a generic type , an `a`

Comment: given you can make the `f` free, yes. For example you could generate a function `f :: Num n => Int -> (Int, n)` where the response is thus a `Num` instance, but the specific one is free. It is however a bit "strange" that this could come up with any type.

Comment: You are essentially asking to construct a function which can return a value for any possible type. You can only achieve that using infinite recursion or using an exceptional value like `undefined`. That does not look very useful -- what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Couldn't you make a new Algebraic DataType or GADT which will be returned by the function (thus fixing the functions return value) but having the possibility of constructing your result depending on the actual return value? (Just a wild thought...)

Comment: I wanted the second variable free since i would want it to be a `String` or a `IO String` for example. **Scenario1** : run the current state get the new state and a log  `Int->(Int,String)` . **Scenario 2** :  get the current state, write something to a file and get the log `Int->(Int,IO String)`

Comment: How you intend to use `makeFree`?

Comment: i would just supply it with the desired method.I would define specialized method :  `freeFunc::Int->(Int,IO String)` and then i would just call in my required scenario `makeFree freeFunc `

Comment: So `makeFree` is accepting function as parameter? Then it is easy, just define `makeFree = State`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you have in mind, but based on the comments, here's a few suggestions.

## Parametrise the function

As given, `f` returns `(Int, String)`, and you can't just change that. What you can do, however, is to parametrise it:

```
f' :: a -> a -> Int -> (Int, a)
f' bigger smaller x | x > 3 = (x, bigger)
                    | otherwise = (x, smaller)
```

This variation no longer returns `(Int, String)`, but rather `(Int, a)`. The price you pay, however, is that you must supply `bigger` and `smaller` as arguments. We'll return to that in a moment, but before we do that, we can turn any function with the general type `s -> (s, a)` into a `State s a` value:

```
make' :: (s -> (s, a)) -> State s a
make' fn = State fn
```

You can now partially apply `f'` to vary the type:

```
*Q56181862> :t make' $ f' "bigger than 3" "smaller than 3"
make' $ f' "bigger than 3" "smaller than 3" :: State Int [Char]
*Q56181862> :t make' $ f' True False
make' $ f' True False :: State Int Bool
```

In the first of the above GHCi examples, the type is `State Int String`, whereas the second example has the type `State Int Bool`.

## Return

From other comments, it seems that you wish to vary between `State Int String` and `State Int (IO String)`. While you can achieve that with the above technique, you can also use `return` in the function itself:

```
f'' :: Monad m => Int -> (Int, m String)
f'' x | x > 3 = (x, return "bigger than 3")
      | otherwise = (x, return "smaller than 3")
```

This varies only the monad, but not the 'return type' `String`. You can provide enough hints to Haskell's type system to inform it that `m` should be `IO`:

```
*Q56181862> :t make' $ f'' :: State Int (IO String)
make' $ f'' :: State Int (IO String) :: State Int (IO String)
```

If you don't want to run the computation in `IO`, you can instead run it in `Identity`, which is also a `Monad`:

```
*Q56181862 Control.Monad.Identity> :t make' $ f'' :: State Int (Identity String)
make' $ f'' :: State Int (Identity String) :: State Int (Identity String)
```

You can now run the computation and pull the `String` out of `Identity` using `runIdentity`.

## Functor

If you make `State s` a functor as well, you can pull the `String` out of `Identity`:

```
*Q56181862 Control.Monad.Identity> :t fmap runIdentity $ make' $ f''
fmap runIdentity $ make' $ f'' :: State Int String
```

The easiest way to do that is to use the `DeriveFunctor` GHC extension:

```
newtype State s a = State { runstate :: s -> (s, a) } deriving Functor
```

...or, you could just use `Control.Monad.State.Lazy` from the `mtl` package...